# IdentityServer4 .Net Core 3 TokenResponse Json is null

Tags: identityserver4, .net-core-3.0

I have this code

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();

        var disco = await Client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync("https://intranet.mycompany.com/");

        if (disco.IsError)
        {
             Console.WriteLine(disco.Error);
            return;
        }

        // request token
        var tokenResponse = await Client.RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync(new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest
        {
            Address = disco.TokenEndpoint,
            ClientId = "Console",
            ClientSecret = "secret",
            Scope = "dev_api",
        });

        if (tokenResponse.IsError)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(tokenResponse.Error);
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(tokenResponse.Json);
        Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
    }
}
```

We just setup intranet.mycompany.com on etc/host to serve local ip address and we setup a self signed certificate. GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync works fine, it connects to IdentityServer, but RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync returns BAD REQUEST

```
{StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
```

{
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Pragma: no-cache
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
  Date: Mon, 14 Oct 2019 15:31:42 GMT
  Expires: -1
}}

Any guidance on how setup identity server 4 .core 3 on local network by IP address with self signed certificate? I want to create a demo infrastructure outside localhost for our clients so we can later publish on the client site.

Comment: BadRequest from IdentityServer contains information about why the request failed, which is available in 'tokenResponse.Error'. So what's the error? It may be that the client 'Console' is not configured to use the client credentials grant type, or the client itself may not be configured at all. The availability of the Discovery Document has nothing to do with this. It is a public document which has no restrictions, unlike a token request.

Comment: Error is null and ErrorType is "Protocol", so https://intranet.mycompany.com/ on localmachine is not valid?

Comment: A protocol error may suggest that the issuer (who created the token), audience (who may accept the token) or the validity time interval (but that is likely not the case) is invalid. So that's where to look. Check your configuration from IdentityServer (client/scope/resource), compared to the configuration in Api/Client startup.

Comment: If I change the URL to https://localhost it works fine. Any guidance to setup the enviroment outside localhost, for example https://<any_local_ip_address> with self signed certificate?

Answer (score 0):

So I accidentally figured out how solve this scenario for local network with HTTPS. You must have 1 self signed certificate named **localhost** to use in identity server Startup class ConfigureServices

```
services.AddSigningCredential("CN=localhost");
```

Then you must have another self signed certificate named **your.local.domain** and setup that domain in etc/host file. You must also setup your web server with this certificate for identity server site.

If you want to connect to identity server from other machine in your local network you have to copy your **your.local.domain** and install it on that machine. Also you have to setup etc/host file on that machine to redirect to the web server.

Example of etc/host on both machines

```
192.168.0.1 your.local.domain
```

Your working ULR for identity server will be something like this

```
https://your.local.domain
```